# Проблема с синхронизацией Gradle по интернету

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Не синхронизируется Gradle при сборке. Выкидывает ошибку

```
Gradle 'chat-android' project refresh failed
Error:Cause: peer not authenticated
```

Гуглил эту ошибку, решения не нашёл, в них предлагали в Gradle.build внести изменения. Дедуктивным методом определил, что Gradle тупо не видит соединения по интернету, т.к. подключил к проекту стороннюю либу из GitGub и он на неё тоже ругнулся, а чистый проект компилится нормально. Прокси не стоит. Ошибка появилась после перестановки винды. Заранее всем спасибо.

Вот лог:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/me/tatarka/gradle-retrolambda/3.2.3/gradle-retrolambda-3.2.3.pom'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRawGet(HttpClientHelper.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performGet(HttpClientHelper.java:70)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultExternalResourceConnector.openResource(DefaultExternalResourceConnector.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.openResource(ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.DefaultExternalResourceRepository.getResource(DefaultExternalResourceRepository.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.getResource(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.downloadStaticResource(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:90)
    ... 102 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:572)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:640)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:118)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:111)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.executeGetOrHead(HttpClientHelper.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:78)
    ... 111 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку проблема возникла после переустановки операционной системы, а обращение к серверу идёт по протоколу HTTPS, то можно предположить, что проблема связана с невалидностью сертификата сервера. Возможны следующие причины возникновения проблемы.

1. Неверное системное время/дата. Либо раньше срока выпуска сертификата сервера, либо позже завершения срока окончания.
2. Отсутствие корневого сертификата центра сертификации. Обновите ОС, установив все имеющиеся обновления или, по меньшей мере, все обновления корневых сертификатов.